# Installing Maven from Eclipse marketplace and using it in command line

Tags: eclipse, maven, command-line

I have installed Maven from Eclipse marketplace. When i use maven from Eclipse IDE, it works fine. I have not set any environment variable for maven. I want to use maven from the command line now. What are the settings i need to do ?

The 'mvn --version' gives me unrecognized command error.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux environment?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend downloading Maven from the apache site rather than put the bin from the Eclipse download into your path.

[Download](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) the latest version [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi), (make sure it is the binary zip) unzip it and then add the directory to your path.

Use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> to bring up Windows properties (assuming you are using Windows) and then click on Advanced System Settings to your left. A new window will open, click `Environment Variables` and then under the `System variables` edit `Path` and then enter the location of the bin directory. For example: `C:\maven-3.1.1\bin;`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the m2e/m2e-wtp plugins uses its own distribution of Maven. You should be able to see this in the `Windows > Preferences > Maven > Installations` .

If you want to use the command line, I suggest you install a stand alone version. It should work fine afterwards.

Windows instructions for installing maven are [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/01/02/how-to-install-maven-on-windows-7/)

Hope this helps.